# How to remove miscellaneous html in specific cms page magento 2 through admin panel?

Tags: magento2

I have a set of code which is called in content -> configuration -> webstore -> Footer ->  Miscellaneous HTML.

I need to remove this code in particular CMS page. Is it possible to remove through admin panel if yes how.

Answer (score 0):

if you add code in miscellaneous HTML code is set to `<head> </head>` tag so you cant remove any code through head

Comment: It is not set to <head></head> tag it's displayed just before ending of <body></body> tag